# How to find out the parent commit of new GIT branch in pre-recive hook?

Tags: git, hook

I try to implement a pre-receive hook in GIT to prevent large size file and specified extension files (*.jar, *.zip).

> pre-receive hook executes once for the receive operation. It takes no
>   arguments, but for each ref to be updated it receives on standard
>   input a line of the format:
>
> (old-value) SP (new-value) SP (ref-name) LF
>
> where (old-value) is the old object name stored in the ref,
>   (new-value) is the new object name to be stored in the ref and
>   (ref-name) is the full name of the ref. When creating a new ref,
>   (old-value) is 40 0.

If user update the files in existing branch, we can get the update file list by using "git diff" command. Then I only need to check the updated files.

But for new branch creation, user can create a new branch based on existig commit and do some change in local repository and then pushed.  For this case, I only want to do the checking on the change use did after existing commit. Any GIT command can help to find out the commit the new branch origate from?

for exaple, user create branch 2 basd on the latest commit in branch 1. After it, create commit2 and commit3. and then push the branch 2.

In hook, (old-value) is 40 0;  (new-value) is commit3; (ref-name) is branch2. I want to get commit1.

> commit3  --branch2
>
> commit2
>
> commit1  -- branch1

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the nearest ancestor that's previously been pushed. However, if merges are being pushed, then there may be multiple such ancestors. So I think you want to check the diff against each of the commits that this command outputs:

```
git rev-list --boundary <new-commit> --not --all | sed -n 's/^-//p'
```